# Why is my jQuery AJAX Call Opening the Response in the Browser?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm completely new to PHP, Javascript, jQuery etc. so I'm finding this very confusing.

I have written a php file that echoes JSON code. I'm then trying to store this response into a Javascript variable on the client, like so:

```
var res;
$.getJSON("my_php_file", { some_param: "param" },
      function(data) {
         res = data;
      }
});
```

Instead, the web browser just opens the response JSON in the current window, rather than saving the result to `res`. Why is this?

Thanks

Comment: Nothing in the code you have provided will give that result.

Comment: How you are calling this code ?

Comment: can you add the PHP code here?

Comment: @Vishal the PHP code has no relevance in this instance.

Comment: how do you call the json php page? on click event or directly after page load?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you handling an onClick event on a link? If so then you are not stopping the event propagation (the default behaviour).

```
$('a#msome_link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var res;
    $.getJSON("my_php_file", { some_param: "param" },
        function(data) {
            res = data;
        }
    });

    return(false); // this is not necessary any more in modern browsers
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure `my_php_file` returns `Content-Type: application/json; charset=<your charset>` header
2. provide json callback:

   my_php_file?cb=?
3. make sure `my_php_file` responds appropriately:

   printf("%s(%s)", $_GET['cb'], $json_response);
4. consider @Mihai Stancu's answer (should be number 0, actually :) )

Comment: BTW Nemoden the 3rd point is JSON**P** behaviour. It is only used if your browser does not recognize `Content-Type: application/json` and you are obligated to return `Content-Type: text/JavaScript` which means the returned text file will be "executed" by the browser just like a `<script>` tag.